# Подключил к index.html стили style.css все правильно , но на странице стиль не отображается

Tags: html, css

Подключил к index.html стили style.css все правильно, но на странице стиль не отображается

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Test</title>" 
    <meta "charset="utf-8" />  
  </head> 
  <body>  
    <h1>Hello World</h1> 
    <h2>Hello World</h</body> 
</html>
```

Вот CSS код который я подключил

```
h1 {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Покажите код, где вы подключили стили

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test</title>" 
<meta "charset="utf-8" />  
</head> 
<body>  
<h1>Hello World</h1> 
<h2>Hello World</h</body> 
</html>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Test</title>" 
<meta "charset="utf-8" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head> 
<body>  
<h1>Hello World</h1> 
<h2>Hello World</h</body> 
</html>

Comment: Есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/677159/edit) для обновления вопросов. И закройте `h2` тег корректно.

Comment: _Подключил к index.html стили style.css_ - а где в html подключение стиля???

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <meta "charset="utf-8" />  
    </head> 
    <body>  
        <h1>Hello World</h1> 
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Файлы index.html и style.css должны находиться в данном случае в одной папке.